# In-Memory Caching and Concurrency Issues

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When requiring to cache files in memory, assuming the following action:

```
public IActionResult Article(int id) {
    String content = MemoryCache.Get<String>(id.ToString());

    if(content == null) {
       MemoryCache.Set<String>(id.ToString(), ReadFile(id), new MemoryCacheEntryOptions() {
                AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        });

        content = MemoryCache.Get<String>(id.ToString());
     }

     return View(content);
}
```

What happens if two or more requests hit the server at the same time? Would this result in the file being read and cached for many times, or would ASP.Net Core MVC handle this issue by default? If so, would it be safe to lock the caching block?

Answer (score 1):

MemoryCache is "threadsafe", but it doesn't mean that two processes can't both miss the cache one after the other (While the first is generating the cache).

Now using the Lock, this really depends on how heavy the function to generate the cache is and comparing that to how heavy a lock may be in your code.

How often are two threads going to be coming in looking for the same cache value? If the answer is not often, then it's probably not worth adding the overhead of locks if the majority of cases it's actually not needed.

Comment: I already figured it out, the answer is that "Yes it does cause the problem" as the Get or Set methods are not thread-safe. On the other hand, `GetOrAdd` or `AddOrUpdate` methods are thread safe which I can use.

Comment: GetOrAdd or AddOrUpdate methods are unfortunately not thread safe. See: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/EyesWideOpenCorrectCachingIsAlwaysHard.aspx